# MS SQL Server Select number of rows is zero I need to return a value

Tags: sql-server

I have this query.

```
 SELECT ISNULL(x.lastLogin,0) AS lastLogin
 FROM
 (
      SELECT u.id,u.lastLogin,u.isAdmin,row_number() 
      OVER(PARTITION BY u.clientid ORDER BY u.lastLogin DESC) AS rownumber 
      FROM users u 
      WHERE (u.isAdmin = -1 AND u.clientid = xxx) AND u.userid Not IN 
      (
         SELECT userID
         FROM Table1
         WHERE groupID = 
             (SELECT groupID FROM Table2
                 WHERE clientid = xxx
                   AND groupName = 'Group 1')
      )
  )x
 WHERE x.rownumber = 1
```

I have searched and tried various methods but can not seem to get a value for when there are zero rows retrieved from the subquery.

The values that can be retrieved from the subquery are a valid date, null if there is no date and no row returned. When I use the current query I will get the proper date if it exists 1900-01-01 if it is null but when zero rows are returned I can not get a value I can do something with. I just get lastlogin column header and not value. How do I get a value set?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also would help if you at least show us the result for the `( ... ) as x` subquery. Most like it you would need make sure the subquery give you the right rows so you could simplify the problem to the subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem. This way the union value can only be on top when there are no other rows.

```
 SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(x.lastLogin,0) AS lastLogin
 FROM
 (
  SELECT u.id,u.lastLogin,u.isAdmin,row_number() 
  OVER(PARTITION BY u.clientid ORDER BY u.lastLogin DESC) AS rownumber 
  FROM users u 
  WHERE (u.isAdmin = -1 AND u.clientid = xxx) AND u.userid Not IN 
  (
     SELECT userID
     FROM Table1
     WHERE groupID = 
         (SELECT groupID FROM Table2
             WHERE clientid = xxx
               AND groupName = 'Group 1')
  )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '',5
  )x
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `WHERE` logic into the select clause, and do a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COUNT(x.lastLogin) = 1 AND x.rownumber = 1
         THEN x.lastLogin
         ELSE GETDATE() END AS lastLogin
FROM
( ... ) x
GROUP BY
    x.lastLogin;
```

Note: I see no point in calling `ISNULL` on `lastLogin`, since if the count be 1, then `lastLogin` cannot possibly be `NULL`.

Comment: The value being retrieved can be null so I need to give it a value. Essentially the value retrieved will be a value, null, or no rows returned.

Comment: Right...but if `lastLogin` is null, then `COUNT(lastLogin)` has to be _zero_, doesn't it?  In that case, the `CASE` expression would return `GETDATE()`.

Comment: I edited the original so show where I am coming from and some info about the data. When I try to move the where rownumber = 1 up it does not like rownumber as a valid column name.

Comment: @dutchlab Then I question whether you are actually running the code you posted in your question, because my suggestion should not be causing this error (though in fact it also may not be working, as you have commented).

Comment: I have copied and pasted that query right from SQL Server Management Studio 2012.